# Website's security certificate

Tags: windows-10, security, internet-explorer, certificate, website

Using Internet Explorer 11, Windows 10 - trying to enter a website — which is not secure — clicking "proceed to website", got the following error:

> “Your PC doesn't trust this website's security certificate.
> The hostname in the website's security certificate differs from the website you are trying to
> visit.
> Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA
> DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID”

It’s a shortcut link but when I’m copying it to a new IE window, the certificate error doesn't appears.

I tried to install certificate, create new shortcut and the following these instructions: “[FIX: There is a problem with website’s security certificate](https://windowsreport.com/there-is-a-problem-with-this-websites-security-certificate/)”

Comment: Try it in Edge. IE11 is pretty much EOL & people are not bothering to check for compatibility any more.

Comment: @Tetsujin - IE11 and Microsoft Edge (Chromium and EdgeHTML) all use the same certificate store.  If IE11 is complaining about the certificate it means Edge will complain about the certificate. **I don't disagree that IE11 shouldn't be used.**  I don't believe using a different browser will resolve the author's problem.

Comment: @ATX-750K - This error is caused by the website's certificate being signed by a certificate authority that isn't trusted.  Without more information we will be unable to help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying, my wondering is why it works fine when i copy the link to a new opened IE window, but in a shortcut method, new shortcut, it is not working smooth as expected.